# php vertica odbc configuration in amazon ec2

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, odbc, vertica

Am need to configure vertica odbc in amazon ec2 machines to fetch datas from existing database for php application. am configured mysql odbc in local ubuntu and run the php examples. But am not sure how to configure vertica odbc in amazon ec2. There is no much document for vertica odbc configuration.

Any one kindly help me for:

configure vertica odbc in amazon ec2.

any alternative method to fetch data from vertica database using php.

please guide me

Comment: I do almost exactly that (with CentOS rather than Ubuntu Linux) How far have you gotten? Is PHP working? What ODBC manager are you using (unixODBC, iODBC)? Have you read the Vertica Developers Guide section on ODBC?

Comment: am using unix odbc. its not working for mme. what abt you

Comment: Does your system have the program 'isql'? It's a command-line ODBC client that I believe comes with unixODBC. You can verify your ODBC connection using that to take PHP out of the equation. Run 'isql ' from the shell and try to run some basic SQL queries.

Comment: hi bpanulla thanks for your reply. configured the odbc vertica. Problem in schema name. now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Does your system have the program 'isql'? It's a command-line ODBC client that I believe comes with unixODBC. You can verify your ODBC connection using that to take PHP out of the equation. Run 'isql   ' from the shell and try to run some basic SQL queries.